# Django User object disappears from request object after successful login and redirect

Tags: django, authentication

I have the following very simple test view:

```
def login_user(request):
    user = auth.authenticate(username='me', password='letmein') #works
    auth.login(request, user) #works
    return redirect(reverse('my_app:login_check'))
```

All of which works as specified in the docs. But when I inspect the request object in the view to which I redirect I see that `user` is an instance of `AnonymousUser` and also that the `session` attribute of request is empty. The database still has the data.

I am using Django 1.10, Python 3.4 and my db is MySQL 5.7.
Please help--many hours already lost on this issue!

Comment: As long as your import is `django.contrib import auth` that looks OK to me. Use your browser tools to make sure that it is sending the correct cookies with the following request. Perhaps some of your [session settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#sessions) are incorrect.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `reverse` with `redirect`. You can do `redirect('my_app:login_check')`

Comment: thanks for the tips I will check it out...

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Alasdair's advice I dug into my session settings and found that `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` was set to `True` which results in cookies only being sent on `HTTPS`. I'm working locally at the moment under Django's web server so none of my cookies were sent. When changed to `False`, everything works.